# Jquery Post ajax variables wont enter PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitting');

    hostingURL = '/<?echo $this->CI->uri->uri_string();?>';
    $('form').attr('action', hostingURL);

    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hostingURL,
        data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        $(document).unbind("submit");
        $("#maincenter").html(data);
        console.log('posted');
    }).fail(function (data) {
        alert('failed');
    });
});
```

this is getting the requested url, and change the form to the action needed, then posting it to the server, and returning data.

server sided i have:

```
echo print_r($_POST);
echo "<br> type: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']." <br>";
```

It seems like whatever i do in my form wont acually submit it. The data back is correct, but from the server side code response i do get: `Array ( ) 1 type: GET` no matter what im doing.

So my question is: How can i acually make the form submit the post data?
The jquery function will be used **on all my forms**, so i need to get every field in the form to be submitted to.

Below is one example form.

example form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea class="textarea col-12" style="height:150px;" id="messageholder" name="profiltekst" placeholder="Profiltekst">
        <? echo $userprofile->profiletext ?>
    </textarea>
    <div class="bottomform">
        <input type="submit" class="makecenter" name="updateprofile" value="Endre profiltekst">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you move the event.preventDefault(); to the beginning of the function?

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: @dquinonez correct, not working :/ updated

Comment: Can you make sure if the ajax call is working? I mean, if the URL you are giving is correct? Also, remove the $('form').attr('action', hostingURL); There is not use to have the form action if you are doing an ajax call to the page.

Comment: yes, the ajax call is working.